# Webpack require ensure large modules

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm using the d3 library.  Its pretty big, so I only want to download the chunk on demand.  I can create the split point with require.ensure, but I'm lost as to how you actually get the library into the scope of the module.  This is as close as I can get, the chunk is downloaded, but d3 is always undefined. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var React = require('react');
var d3;

require.ensure([], function(require){

    d3 = require('d3');

});

var Chart = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var props = this.props;
        var width = props.width;

        //d3 is undefined here
        var xScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([
            0, 111
        ]).range([
            0, width
        ]);

        return (
            <g>
            </g>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Chart;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my understanding the mechanism goes like this:

```
require.ensure(["<file-path or module name>"], function(moduleExportsValue) {
    var myModule = require("<file-path or module name>");
});
```

**for your specific example:**

```
require.ensure(["d3"], function() {
    var d3 = require("d3");
    // do something with d3
});
```

*Edit: It's very helpful for stuff that is not immediately visible in the app. Such as dialogs, modals, overlays.*

```
onButtonClick: function(event) {
    this.showLoader();

    var self = this;
    require.ensure("path/to/dialog", function() {
        self.hideLoader();

        var dialog = require("path/to/dialog");
        dialog.open();
    });
},
```

Comment: Hi - would that also work? `require(['d3'], function(obj) { var d3 = obj;})` as in [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack#a-small-example-of-whats-possible)

Comment: Hi - the normal require function loads the dependency right away. Use `require.ensure(['d3'], function() { var d3 = require('d3'); })`. If d3 has a module.exports statement you can use it like this: `require.ensure(['d3'], function(d3) { console.log( d3 ); })` ... to asynchronously load the dependency.